# Looping library which returns a promise - sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronization

I'm scratching my head over this code: I read folder content, loop received files through mammoth convert (which returns a promise) and then I create an object which I would like to render.
I've tried with async and promises but was never able to make it synchronous. Could you please advise?

```
fs.readdir('Documents', function (err, files) {
    files.forEach(function (file) {      
      mammoth.convertToHtml({path: "Documents/"+file},options)
      .then(function(result){
          var html = result.value; // The generated HTML
          var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
          docContent.push({
            "skillName" : file,
            "skillData" : html
          })
      }).done()
   });
});

res.render("index",{docContent:docContent});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had hard time to understand concept of gathering result of promise too ^^;.
I think it is good start point to remember `Promise.all()` can gather result of Promise.

Please try below.

```
    fs.readdir('Documents', function (err, files) {
        // convertingJob = [Promise, Promise,...]  
        const convertingJob = files.map(function(file) {  
            // just return promise and it will make above convertingJob array 
            return mammoth.convertToHtml({path: "Documents/"+file},options) 
                  .then(function(result){
                        var html = result.value; // The generated HTML
                        var messages = result.messages; // Any messages, such as warnings during conversion
                        // docContent.push({
                        //     "skillName" : file,
                        //     "skillData" : html
                        // })
                        return {
                            "skillName" : file,
                            "skillData" : html
                        }
                   })
                   // .done() // I'm not sure this is necessary
         });

         Promise.all(convertingJob) // Gather(wait) all Promise results!
         .then(jobResults => {      // jobResults would be array of objects returned by mammoth 
            res.render("index",{docContent:jobResults});
         })
    });
```

Comment: This works perfect . Thank you very much! Not really sure why done() spoiled my efforts :)